# Power of a discrete cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $F(x)$ be a distribution function of discrete random variable $X$ and $r$ a positive integer. Show that $F(x)^r$ is also a distribution function.

I tried in following manner: for F to be a distribution function, sum of F over all values of x should be 1. So for F^r also, sum of F^r(x) for all x should be 1. I have verified this for r=2,3,4. But, i am not able to prove it for any r. It is getting very complex. I think i am stuck in the series problem. 
I squared the sum of F(x) over all x, and then separated out sum of F^2(x) for all x, and using the sum of all F(x) as unity gave sum of F^2(x) for all x, also as unity. Similarly sum of F^3(x) for all x, and sum of F^4(x) for all x, also came out to be unity. 
But, powering it r times and then getting sum of sum of F^r(x) for all x, is difficult and conplex for me.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Add that to your question (not in a comment).

Comment: $0^r = 0, 1^r = 1.$ And if $x > y$ then what about $x^t$ and $y^t.$ So exactly where is your difficulty and why are you messing with problematic series? Finally, what is wrong with @drhab's Answer (+1)?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways.

You can prove that $F^r(x)$ has all [properties of a cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Properties).

---

Secondly, let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be iid random variables having $F$ as cumulative distribution function.

Then also $\max(X_1,\dots,X_r)$ is a random variable.

What is its cumulative distribution function?